# How compare too similar files

Tags: c, shell, awk

I have two text files like this:

line are like => SITE.MACHINE.VARIABLE_NAME=VARIABLE_VALUE

```
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.CHRONO_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE=0
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC13.CHRONO_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE=0
DEMO-WEB.WAC7.XN_TCP_SERVICE_PDD_PORT=32099
...
```

They are already sort -u

I have to find out which lines are in one file or in another or have been modified (I do not care about the common ones), like **sdiff** command.
But the files are have too similar lines that create the diff error.

I'm thinking of diff on the left side of "=" and, if ok, check for the right side.
I am looking for a solution that prints an output like sdiff or kind of.

output wanted exemple :

```
File1                                                         | File2
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC10.SAR_PARI_SUJET_A_COTES="1:0:1:1:0:0:0:0:0"  | CPM-NOMINAL.WAC10.SAR_PARI_SUJET_A_COTES="1:0:1:1:0:0:0:1:0"
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.CHRONO_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE=1              | CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.CHRONO_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE=0
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PARIS_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE=1               | CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PARIS_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE=0
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PARIS_SANS_EMISSION_KEEPALIVE=1             | CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PARIS_SANS_EMISSION_KEEPALIVE=0
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PROTOCOLE_PDD=2                             | CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PROTOCOLE_PDD=3
                                                              > CPM-NOMINAL.WAC7.SQL_PROC_INIT_XAPDD_MBN_TEST="p_initialiser"
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC8.FAIRE_VERIF_CHAINAGE=FALSE                   | CPM-NOMINAL.WAC8.FAIRE_VERIF_CHAINAGE=TRUE
DEMO-WEB.WAC7.XN_TCP_SERVICE_PDD_PORT=3201                    | DEMO-WEB.WAC7.XN_TCP_SERVICE_PDD_PORT=32099
DEMO-WEB.WAC7.XN_TCP_SERVICE_SAR_PORT=3201                    | DEMO-WEB.WAC7.XN_TCP_SERVICE_SAR_PORT=3204
```

Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do mention more clear samples of Input and expected output in your post along with your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem and let us know then.

Comment: Why isn't the `comm` command sufficient for this?  I don't see what you want to do that's different.

Comment: Read about [mcve] and update your Q with 2 sample inputs that cover all cases you expect to encounter AND the required output from those inputs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way of doing this with traditional tools and pipelines. I use the terminology key and value as the file looks like

```
key = value
```

The following list of commands give you possible answers:

```
# lines common between file1 and file2
grep -F -f file1 file2
# lines in file2 not in file1
grep -v -F -f file1 file2
# changed key values from file1 to file2
cut -d'=' -f1 file1 | grep -F -f - <(grep -v -F -f file1 file2)
# keys in file1 but not in file2
cut -d'=' -f1 file1 | grep -v -F -f - file2
# keys in file2 but not in file1
cut -d'=' -f1 file2 | grep -v -F -f - file1
```

Or you can just go for one simple awk, this is not the most optimised, but gives a clean output:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{FS=" *= *"}
    {key=$1;value=$2}
    (NR==FNR){a[key]=value; next}
    {b[key] = value }
    END {
       for (key in a) if (key in b) {
           print (a[key] == b[key] ? "COMM" : "DIFF"), key,"=",a[key],"<=>",b[key]
           delete a[key]
           delete b[key] 
       }
       for (key in a) {
           print "UNI1", key,"=",a[key]
       }
       for (key in b) {
           print "UNI2", key,"=",b[key]
       }
    }' file1 file2
```

This will produce some output looking like

```
 COMM key1 = val1 <=> val1
 COMM key2 = val2 <=> val2
 DIFF key3 = val31 <=> val32      
 COMM key4 = val4 <=> val4
 UNI1 key5 = val5
 UNI2 key6 = val6
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this can be done with `join`

```
$ join -a1 -a2 -e"---" -t= -o1.1,1.2,2.2,2.1 file1 file2 | column -ts=

CPM-NOMINAL.WAC10.SAR_PARI_SUJET_A_COTES         "1:0:1:1:0:0:0:0:0"             "1:0:1:1:0:0:0:1:0"  CPM-NOMINAL.WAC10.SAR_PARI_SUJET_A_COTES
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.CHRONO_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE   1                               0                    CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.CHRONO_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PARIS_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE    1                               0                    CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PARIS_SANSREPONSE_KEEPALIVE
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PARIS_SANS_EMISSION_KEEPALIVE  1                               0                    CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PARIS_SANS_EMISSION_KEEPALIVE
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PROTOCOLE_PDD                  2                               3                    CPM-NOMINAL.WAC12.PROTOCOLE_PDD
---                                              ---                             "p_initialiser"      CPM-NOMINAL.WAC7.SQL_PROC_INIT_XAPDD_MBN_TEST
CPM-NOMINAL.WAC8.FAIRE_VERIF_CHAINAGE            FALSE                           TRUE                 CPM-NOMINAL.WAC8.FAIRE_VERIF_CHAINAGE
DEMO-WEB.WAC7.XN_TCP_SERVICE_PDD_PORT            3201                            32099                DEMO-WEB.WAC7.XN_TCP_SERVICE_PDD_PORT
DEMO-WEB.WAC7.XN_TCP_SERVICE_SAR_PORT            3201                            3204                 DEMO-WEB.WAC7.XN_TCP_SERVICE_SAR_PORT
```

common values can be eliminated with piping to `awk '$2!=$3'`